# WPF Issue when i open a second Window and until second click on any button inside, it works

Tags: wpf, events, click, touch, focus

First of all,
I've been reading some quiestions before and looks still no answer.
My machine's OS is Win7, but the testings machine has Win10 Pro insider Preview. IDE is VS2013 for develop, the framework i'm using 4.0. **IMPORTANT** I'm using a touch screen system for my testings.

FYI

I have in my project two windows the mainwindow opens a second window. In the 2nd Win i have several buttons. But the issue appears when i want to click on any button and see the action. But it doesn't performs any action until the second click. In my opinion it maybe is problem with focus. But i tried to set manually the focus() method, and it still doesn't works. The weird thing is when i click on any button in the mainwindow it doesn't matter if i'm using touchevents or mouseevents the button performs the action and the second doesn't. That is the weird issue!

Thanks for you time,

This is my code **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Testings.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="664.5" Width="955" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid x:Name="Principal">
        <Button Content="Abrir ventana" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="81" Margin="19,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="167" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Grid Width="300" Height="300">
            <ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  x:Name="PopButton" Content="Pop"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now i'll show you the cs **MainWindow.cs**

```
namespace Testings
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ventana2 v = new ventana2();
            v.ShowDialog();
            v.Close();            
        }            

    }
}
```

The second window **ventana2.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Pruebas.ventana2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ventana2" Height="300" Width="300" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid x:Name="principal">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF1133AA" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="205*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="87*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Hello this is a second window" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="34,210,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="White" FontSize="16">
            <Label.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="#FFB2F1FF" BlurRadius="4" ShadowDepth="0"/>
            </Label.Effect>
        </Label>
        <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Change the background color" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="131" Margin="45,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="221" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn_close" Content="Close" Width="70" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Click="btn_close_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The codebehind **ventana2.cs**

```
namespace Testings
{
    public partial class ventana2 : Window
    {
        bool flag = false;
        public ventana2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            if(flag == false)
            {
                principal.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                flag = true;
            }
            else if (flag == true)
            {
                principal.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        private void btn_close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally**, i remember you that the system i'm using is a touch screen!